# How can you duo Roshan at level 1?

Tags: dota-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What kind of a team setup is required to kill Roshan before the match begins?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52223/what-kind-of-a-team-setup-is-required-to-kill-roshan-before-the-match-begins)

A friend and myself recently nailed down how to duo Roshan at level 1 using Ursa (with fury swipes) and Skeleton King (with vampiric aura).  I've also witnessed an Ursa (fury swipes) and Lich (frost armor) managing to take down Roshan before the game started.

What other two hero/ability combinations can consistently kill Roshan as soon as the game begins?

Comment: how the heck do you do it with ursa + lich? that life leech is pretty crucial in keeping ursa alive.

Comment: @Spartacus Wisp tanks damage then tethers to Ursa and uses a healing potion on himself. The heal is shared by Ursa as Ursa tanks it. Repeat as necessary, usually twice.

Comment: @Decency He was asking about Lich, not Wisp. My guess is the pretty standard way of changing Rosh's aggro to the 2nd hero while Ursa salves and continues to attack.

Comment: @Kotsu Oops. I've never tried it, but I guess it's possible. The Frost Armor of Lich would help significantly, but I think it would be tight and somewhat luck dependent.

Comment: @Decency Definitely, there are much safer pairs of heroes to do level 1 Rosh with than those two.