# Which strategy allows you to beat Rosh the most times in Diretide?

Tags: dota-2

So far I know of two strategies.

1. Pick carries, beat him to death with damage items.
2. Pick people with burst damage (Lion, Lina) and use an etheral blade and lots of maxed out Dagons

Does anyone know which is better?  Or if there's a different better one?

Note: Better can be defined as doing more damage per second, thus killing him faster (therefor this isn't a subjective question)

EDIT:

After searching some more I noticed [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/142359/most-effective-hero-against-roshan) but I'm hoping for a more exact answer with some numbers backing it up (I know it's lots of work, but maybe I'll be the one to do it and post it)

Comment: It's pretty much a dupe of the question you linked to. My answer has some flaws but it's still the same question and you're welcome to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'll agree with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to tweet by tobiwan, which is a link to a reddit article,
this is the best strategy

[image: Rosh Strategy]

So picking heroes like Phantom Assassin, Anti-Mage, Sven, Troll Warlord and Alchemist should allow you to do a lot of damage.

This works because the other team don't take damage from your attacks. The cleave damage ignores Roshan's high armour.

So the people directly attacking Rosh should pack some desolators.

[Original Tweet](https://twitter.com/TobiWanDOTA/status/402559856764145664/photo/1)